# Dos if seguidos pero el primer if no se ejecuta nunca. Es tapado por el segundo

Tags: php, mysql, condiciones, variables

Tengo una consulta sql, y si da algún valor la variable $like obtiene el valor quitarlike, y si no el valor ponerlike. Después hay un if, en el que si la variable $like tiene el valor quitarlike, da a la variable $varg el valor 1, y luego otro if nen el que si la variable $like tiene el valor poner like, da a la variable $varg el valor 2. El caso es que fuera de estos if, imprimo la variable $varg para ver su valor, y da igual que $like sea quitarlike o ponerlike, que siempre imprime 2. ¿Porqué es esto? ¿Alguna solución o explicación? Muchas gracias.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM likes WHERE idpublicacion= '".$idpublicacion."' AND usuariolike = 'Paquito'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
    $like = "quitarlike";
}else{
    $like = "ponerlike";
}
if($like = "quitarlike"){
$varg = "1";
}
if($like = "ponerlike"){
$varg = "2";
}
echo $varg;
```

PD:He de aclarar que es un ejemplo simplificado porque lo que creo que ocurre es que el primer if nunca se ejecuta, o si se ejecuta es tapado por el segundo. Gracias por todo.

Comment: En los `if` para comparar igualdad se utiliza `==` (Dos signos igual). Un solo signo igual significa asignación, no comparación.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato Muchisimas gracias. Ese era el problema. Que tonto he sido.

Comment: En la vida diaria utilizamos la palabra/concepto de "igual" en dos situaciones diferentes. Al comparar dos objetos decimos si `$like` es igual a `"ponerlike"`... y el segundo es al asignar un valor, `$varg` es igual a `"2"`. Pero en el segundo caso en programación sería mejor utilizar, se asigna `"2"` a `$varg` para evitar confusiones.

Answer (score 1):

Estoy muy de acuerdo con las correcciones anteriores, claramente hay que diferenciar "=" (asignacion) de "==" (igualdad) y de "===" (igualdad estricta); además me gustaría agregar otro punto, más como pregunta que como corrección: ¿por qué no combinar los if ya que suponen la misma condicional?, algo así como:

```
{
if($mostrar == mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
    $like = "quitarlike";
    $varg = "1";
}else{
    $like = "ponerlike";
    $varg = "2";
}
}
```

yo lo haría así, creo que se entiende más y es más simple, pero soy bastante nuevo en la programación

Answer (score 0):

Te falta un igual en los condicionales ya que para comparar de resultados necesitas doble igual. También acostumbra-te a declarar las variables que vas a usar fuera de los casos if...

Correcciones:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM likes WHERE idpublicacion= '".$idpublicacion."' AND 
usuariolike = 'Paquito'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
// aquí es un fallo   
$like = "";
// Aqui es el Otro Fallo
if($mostrar == mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
    $like = "quitarlike";
}else{
    $like = "ponerlike";
}
// aquí es el otro fallo 
if($like == "quitarlike"){
$varg = "1";
}
// aquí es el otro fallo
if($like == "ponerlike"){
$varg = "2";
}
echo $varg;
```